# Rails/Hotwire - don't cache Turbo frames on restoration visits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo, hotwire

I have a page that contains a Turbo frame which loads some content from another URL using the `src` param.

Now when I click a link to navigate away from that page and then press "Back" in my browser, it's what Turbo calls a "restoration" visit, on which it displays the cached page without loading it again from the server.

This is exactly what I want EXCEPT for the Turbo frame - it should never be cached and always be reloaded from the URL it has as its `src` param.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The `turbo-data-permanent` attribute may be what you're looking for:

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

Comment: No unfortunately not.